# How to pass the value to the AuthenticationProvider from HttpRequest in Micronaut java with Jnunit 5

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

Using Micronaut HttpClient to perform the HTTP calls in Junit 5 testing.

I am trying to pass the value to AuthenticationProvider using HttpRequest as below

```
@MicronautTest
public class ProductCreateTest extends TestContainerFixture {

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    HttpClient client;


    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should create the product")
    void shouldCreateTheProduct() {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.POST("/product", new ProductModel())
            .bearerAuth(bearerAccessRefreshToken.getAccessToken());
        request.setAttribute("fb_product", "owner");
        HttpResponse < ProductModel > rsp = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, ProductModel.class);
        var item = rsp.body();
    }
}
```

Here I am setting an attribute as `request.setAttribute("fb_product", "owner");` and in the authentication provider I am trying to access the attribute as below

[image]

```
@Singleton
@Requires(env = Environment.TEST)
public record AuthenticationProviderFixture(Configuration configuration) implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(HttpRequest<?> httpRequest, AuthenticationRequest<?, ?> authenticationRequest) {
        return Flux.create(emitter -> {
            if (authenticationRequest.getIdentity().equals(configuration.Username()) && authenticationRequest.getSecret().equals(configuration.Password())) {
                var attributeValue = httpRequest.getAttribute("fb_product");
                HashMap<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
                emitter.next(AuthenticationResponse.success((String) authenticationRequest.getIdentity(), attributes));
                emitter.complete();
            } else {
                emitter.error(AuthenticationResponse.exception());
            }
        }, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.ERROR);
    }
}
```

[image]

The attribute is not mapped and this provides an null value `var attributeValue = httpRequest.getAttribute("fb_product");`

What is the best approach to pass the data from HttpRequest to AuthenticationProvider

There is a concept of the token generator, however, with the token generator on the security rule, the authentication is null.

Inject the `TokenGenerator` and create a token

```
Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("fb_product","owner");
        var claimGenerator = tokenGenerator.generateToken(claims);
```

Comment: I don't believe request attributes are sent over http.  They are for internal data sharing of data bound to a request

Comment: In the real app what is setting the attribute?

Comment: @tim_yates thanks for the answer, is it the header that we send the data ? Even I am not sure how to send over header, can you please show me a example if it is header.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I am not sure about this. Can you please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a header to the request:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.POST("/product", new ProductModel())
        .bearerAuth(bearerAccessRefreshToken.getAccessToken())
        .header("fb_product", "owner");
```

To retrieve the header:

```
Optional<String> fbOwner = request.getHeaders().findFirst("fb_owner");
```

Comment: What is the best approach to pass the value, is it a header ??

Answer (score 0):

You don't set attributes in the HTTP Client request.

what are you trying to achieve? Mock a user being logged in?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to mock the user, with certain claims